# How to make 3D request and return the payload

Tags: java, 3d-secure

I want to make a request to ACS server with PAReq values using Spring WebFlux. I tried this:

```
WebClient.Builder builder = WebClient.builder();
WebClient client = builder.build();
client.post().uri("https://securecode.lisa.mastercard.com/acspage/cap")
                .header("PaReq", "eJxdUdtu6jAQ/BXEB8R2uCRBiyUKB....")
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class).block();
```

What is the proper way to implement the user redirect? Currently I'm making a request using Server-side Java code? I should make the call and return the payload to the user when he opens the link returned from Spring?

Spring endpoint opened by the user:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/redirect/to_acquirer/{token}", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
          MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
              MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
  public ModelAndView handleRedirectMessage(@PathVariable("token") String token,
          @RequestBody PaymentTransaction transaction, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

        .......

        // TO DO add here POST with PAReq and redirect the user to the page.
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + url);
```

}